# How to calculate 2 digits different number system than decimal [Python]

Tags: python, numbers, system, operation

I can't calculate 2 digits in different number system than decimal.
Here's an example.

```
operation = "101 + 101"
result = eval(operation)
print(result)
```

and result is 202, but I would like to calculate it in binary where the result is 10 so whats the idea to do this.
I know I can 0b before number but i can't do this in my situation.
Is there like library or smth that do calculate it?

Comment: you calculate the operation with regulars numbers and transform it to your desire base to display it

Comment: if you are taking string as your input, to transform it to to normal int using the optional second argument of base for int constructor: `int("101",2)`

Answer (score 1):

if what you take as input is a string with some operation that you want to pass to eval, you can use a regular expression to append "0b" to the numbers and then pass that to eval

```
>>> import re
>>> operation = "101 + 101"
>>> re.sub("([01]+)",r"0b\1",operation)
'0b101 + 0b101'
>>> eval('0b101 + 0b101')
10
>>>
```

to extend that to handle both base 2 and 16 we can make it into a function

```
>>> def toBase(text,base):
        if base==2:
            num="01"
        elif base==16:
            num ="0123456789abcdefABCDEF"
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError
        new = f"int('\\1',{base})"
        return re.sub(f"([{num}]+)",new,text)


>>> toBase("E39 + 93",16)
"int('E39',16) + int('93',16)"
>>> toBase("101 + 101",2)
"int('101',2) + int('101',2)"
>>> eval(toBase("E39 + 93",16))
3788
>>> eval(toBase("101 + 101",2))
10
>>>
```

Comment: Regular exp is some answer but isn't it only in particular case? For example I also need to calculate from hexadecimal "E39 - 93" and how to write reg exp to that case.

Comment: how many bases you want to handle just 2 and 16? any base whatsoever from 2 to 60?

Comment: just binary and hexadecimal

Comment: @Kubskyy I make an update for a function that handle both binary and hexadecimal

Answer (score 0):

You can tell int() function in which numerical base you want a string.

```
int('101', 2) + int('101', 2)
Out[2]: 10
```

Comment: I know that but is there a way to convert the whole expression "101 + 101" directly into binary operation to evaluate into 10

Answer (score 0):

You can manually try adding the two numbers up using a 'for' cycle.
You will be adding up every digit on their own.
The way you can get each digit is by having that number%10 which will give you the right digit of the number.
There needs to be an 'if' statement in your cycle that checks whether when your adding up the two numbers their sum gets higher than the allowed value(which will be determined by the number system that you're using. in your case the sum of the two digits shouldn't be higher than 1). in the occasion that the sum does get higher you can handle that by saving it in another variable for the right time(which will be when your adding up the next digits in line)
at the end you will need to have your number divided by 10 to go to the next digits.

Comment: This answer could be improved if you can provide code snippets to demonstrate the operations you are describing.